# Are there languages that have different forms of "we"?

Tags: pronouns, ambiguity, clusivity

I find the pronoun "we" to be lacking due to its ambiguity regarding whether or not the listener and/or a 3rd party is included. Are there languages which address this by having either multiple forms of "we" or other disambiguation solutions?

Comment: Yes, there are. This question is already answered [here](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/14438/1270)

Comment: You have some examples in Wikipediaentry for [we](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/We) (and more details in the [clusivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clusivity) entry )